# Am I configuring the IR2104 incorrectly?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, buck

I'm trying to make a buck converter using IR2104 and IRFZ44N. The buck converter is controlled using Arduino's PWM. I'll post my schematic below.

Based on the datasheet, the HO signal will be the same as IN and the LO signal will be the invert of IN if SD is in logic 1, and if the SD is in logic 0, all HO and LO are off.

My IR2104 acts like this:

- SD = 1, HO = IN, LO = 5V
- SD = 0, HO = 5V, LO = invert of IN

I bought IR2104 from 2 different shop and both acts the same. Is the IR2104 faulty or am I configuring the circuit wrong?

Edit: adding some information, my PWM is 50 kHz.

[image: Buck converter circuit]

Comment: U1 in your schematic is an IR2184. The text of your post, however, refers to an IR2104, which is not found in the schematic. Please correct whichever is wrong.

Comment: Yes IR2104 is not available in proteus, I use IR2104 in my physical circuit @MathKeepsMeBusy

Comment: Not possible to edit the text field?

Comment: You know that the IR2104 and IR2184 do not have the same pin-outs, right?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes, they have a different pinout, but i connect my physical circuit the way i connect in the schematics.

Comment: @MiNiMe It's possible to change the name only, but if you change it, you can't simulate it.

Comment: So that means you're do a sim with the wrong part..?

Comment: The datasheet says nothing about R2 and R3! Why did you put them there? They are not needed. R4 and R5 are ten times larger than what they need to be. These are ‘gate stoppers’ not current limiters. The IR2104 is more than capable of driving those mosfets directly and those resistors are to stop ringing due to inductance in the Source circuit. Those 1N4007 diodes are way too slow, use high speed diodes.and read the ir2104 datasheet.

Comment: @MiNiMe my computer can't run the sim... i only make the schematic so it's easier to read

Comment: @Kartman Yes, indeed R2 and R3 is not it datasheet. My upper classmate suggest it to avoid floating and discharge the gate. I use sako243's answer and it help mostly with the discharge of capacitor. 

I didn't know that it was gate stopper not current limiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Gswffye says is the main issue with your circuit, Vs should be connected between the two FETs.

There is an app note by Infineon I came across (unfortunately can't find it at the moment) about sizing of the bootstrap capacitor and perhaps more importantly the properties of D1 in your circuit. Most notably the diode should have a fast recovery time (sub 100ns ideally) to prevent transients from the switch node flowing back onto the supply rail (particularly important when the FET supply is greater than Vcc).

It may also be appropriate to add a diode across the series gate resistors to aid in turning off the FETs quickly. Under your current schematic the gate capacitance of the FET has to discharge through the resistor which slows it down and results in the FET staying in the Ohmic region for longer. This may result in the FET blowing as it heats up.

With regards to the gate resistors consult the datasheet of the IR2104 and see what it's drive capabilities are, you want the resistor to be large enough to limit current to protect the output circuits but ideally as small as possible so that the gate capacitor charges up as quickly as possible resulting in the FET turning on as quickly as possible. The pull down should be between the gate and source. The size of this doesn't really matter too much, tens of k or higher are fine - it's there primarily to ensure that the gate doesn't float (particularly during start up). Remember you're in effect making a potential divider here between the output pin of the driver, the gate and the source, too low a value will result in not a high enough Vgs to turn on.

The point about transients isn't to be taken lightly - I recently built a ~1kW 340V H bridge driver for a motor using the IR2104. Without the additional protection (gate diodes, pull-downs and fast recovery diodes) the driver and FETs would die.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try your suggestion with the diode in the MOSFET's gate and the Vs one.

Answer (score 0):

Vs is not connected to the switch node.

Typically I would also put the pull down on the high side FET to the switch node instead of to ground (across Vgs of the FET). Your pull downs are very strong and your series resistors are quite large

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you have any suggestion how much the pull down and current limiter for the MOSFET?

Answer (score 0):

> It may also be appropriate to add a diode across the series gate resistors to aid in turning off the FETs quickly. Under your current schematic the gate capacitance of the FET has to discharge through the resistor which slows it down and results in the FET staying in the Ohmic region for longer. This may result in the FET blowing as it heats up.
> -Sako243

This does help with most of my circuit. Regarding the strange output of IR2104 (differ from datasheet), I use PWM on both SD and IN to solve this.

The reason why the IR2104 is acting strange might be "Chinese quality", I can't find the original one (at least in my country)

Comment: Don't give comments as an answer, instead use the Add comment under the answer you wish to relate to.

Comment: ...Or edit the question to add relevant supporting information. Thanks!